# Using HTaccess to redirect to a subfolder if it contains the requested file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, caching

I'm trying to load some content from the database, and cache it in a folder on the server. Currently, I'm using this code to catch requests to `http://localhost/files/hash.png` and pass the hash and filetype to a PHP file which returns the data.

Files can have any extension, so I need to either catch the full filename (that's fine), or split it into name and extension (also fine).

Here's my HTaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^files/([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$ getfile.php?hash=$1&ext=$2 [NC,L]
```

The problem is, I'm now needing to tell it to try to find `hash.png` in a subfolder of `files` called `cache` (i.e. `files/cache/hash.png`). This would need to be loaded instead of the PHP file, should the file exist in that folder.

Can anyone help? I'm struggling to get it working. This is to do a kind of caching on files stored in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^files/(.*) files/cache/$1 [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule *. - [L]
RewriteRule ^files/cache/(.*) files/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^files/([^\.]+)\.([^\.]+)$ getfile.php?hash=$1&ext=$2 [NC,L]
```

Here it's rewriting the file name to alter the path to `file/cache/` before testing if it exists.  If it exists, don't change the file name and stop rules (with `[L]`).  If it doesn't exist, rewrite the file name back to what it was and continue with the rules you already have.